# unsupported operand types for //: 'str', 'int'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have found this function to format the exception that raised

```
def format_trace_except(self, sysexecinfo, smessage= ''):
   """ Trace exceptions """
   exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sysexecinfo
   i, j = (traceback.extract_tb(exc_traceback, 1))[0][0:2]
   k = (traceback.format_exception_only(exc_type, exc_value))[0]
   trace('Err : ' + smessage + k + i + ', line ' + str(j))
   return k
```

when I am using this function I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 121, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, e)
  File "/home/xxxxxxxxxxxxx", line 60, in process_exception
    return self.handle_500(request, exception)
  File "/home/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", line 64, in handle_500
    response = self.format_trace_except(sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", line 74, in format_trace_except
    x = trace('Err : ' + smessage + k + i + ', line ' + str(j))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 1058, in trace
    return getinnerframes(sys.exc_info()[2], context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 1043, in getinnerframes
    framelist.append((tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 1005, in getframeinfo
    start = lineno - 1 - context//2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'str' and 'int'
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop importing `*` from `inspect`.

Comment: then I am getting NameError

NameError: global name 'trace' is not defined

Comment: Then go back and figure out how the function you "found" actually works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736080/sys-exc-info1-type-and-format-in-python-2-71 

I have found this here..can u tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're picking up half-broken fragments of code and putting them into your programs.

Answer (score 1):

[`inspect.trace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.trace) accept only one parameter: `context`. And it should be `int` object.